# Triple DES Java not working

Tags: java, des

I'm using this programs code [Programs code full](http://www.pracspedia.com/INS/DES-java.html) and i can't figure it out why wouldn't my Triple DES work. How and what did i try?

1. I added 3key inputs (as well arrays for keybits) that i would use to encrypt the hex and converted them:

   ```
       String keyy1 = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
       int keyBitstriple1[] = new int[64];
           for(int i=0 ; i < 14 ; i++) {
           String s = Integer.toBinaryString(Integer.parseInt(keyy1.charAt(i) + "", 16));
                   while(s.length() < 4) {
                       s = "0" + s;
                   }
                   for(int j=0 ; j < 4 ; j++) {
                       keyBitstriple1[(4*i)+j] = Integer.parseInt(s.charAt(j) + "");
                   }
               }
   ```
2. Then i encrypted the hexa:

   ```
       System.out.println("1st encrypt");
       int outputBits[] = permute(inputBits, keyBitstriple1, false);
       int outputBits2[] = Arrays.copyOf(outputBits, outputBits.length);
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("2nd enrypt");
       int outputBits3[] = permute(outputBits2, keyBitstriple2, false);
       int outputBits4[] = Arrays.copyOf(outputBits3, outputBits3.length);
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("3rd enrypt");
       int outputBits5[] = permute(outputBits4, keyBitstriple3, false);
    );
    int outputBits6[] = Arrays.copyOf(outputBits5, outputBits5.length); 
   //a copy of end encrypt
   ```

**Encryption is completely correct, even when i check with online DES encryption software results was the same.**

3. Then i saved the end encryption in outputBits6 and made a user enter 3 more keys to what decrypt that encrypted text. **The same as first step.**

   ```
    String keyy4 = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    String keyy5 = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
    String keyy6 = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
   ```
4. Then i took first user entered key to decrypt the hexa text. (outputbits6)

   ```
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("First decrypt");
       int outputBits7[] =  permute(outputBits6, keyBitstriple4, true);
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("2nd decrypt");
       int outputBits8[] = permute(outputBits7, keyBitstriple5, true);
       System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
       System.out.println("3rd decrypt");
       int outputBits9[] = permute(outputBits8, keyBitstriple6, true);
   ```

Every time decryption is wrong and i can't figure it out why but encryption is correct. [MY FULL CODE](https://gist.github.com/e1cd910ad2ec86fe1cf9ee07c4f83936)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Triple DES is not very secure (112-bits of security for a 168-bit key) and should not be used for new work, the current encryption standard is AES.

Comment: @zaph Thanks, i just want to understand how can i make it work, AES is next on my list. :) Cheers have a nice day!

Comment: 1. One thing you are missing is that generally 3DES encryption is `ede`: encrypt with the 1st key, decrypt with the 2nd key and encrypt with the 3rd key. The reverse for decryption. 2. 3DES was a hack to make DES more secure and `ede` for upgrade compatibility with DES.

Comment: @zaph Thanks actually that was the problem. <3

Comment: @zaph any idea why in hex it does not allow F or f ?

Comment: The keys are to short, they need to be 8-bytes. While DES uses a 56-bit key it is in 8-bytes, the lsb in each byte is not used. 8-bytes * 7-bits = 56-bits. The implementation of `permute` is wrong. **do not use it**.

Comment: Nota Bene: The code on **pracspedia.com** is **not to be trusted**, at least some is completely wrong.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that is missing is that generally 3DES encryption is `ede`: encrypt with the 1st key, decrypt with the 2nd key and encrypt with the 3rd key. The reverse `ded` for decryption.